# How to select unique value from two columns if third have the same value

Tags: sql, mariadb

TABLE:

```
id second_id status
1  2         1
2  1         0
1  3         1
3  1         1
1  4         1
4  1         1
```

I try to select only this unique value where the pair have the same status
OUTPUT:

```
id second_id status
1  3         1
1  4         1
```

I try with

```
SELECT table.id, table.second_id, table.status FROM table 
WHERE table.id = 1 and table.status = 1
```

but this return of course bad results ;) 
Thx for help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to `JOIN` the table to itself, looking for matching `id` and `second_id` values with the same `status`. We also check that the second table's `id` value is greater than the first to avoid duplicates:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM test t1
JOIN test t2 ON t2.id = t1.second_id
            AND t2.second_id = t1.id
            AND t2.status = t1.status
            AND t2.id > t1.id
```

Output:

```
id  second_id   status
1   3           1
1   4           1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4zMhLmXVrQDioD1wUVq1EB/0)

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.second_id = t.id and
                    t2.id = t.second_id and
                    t2.status = t.status
             );
```

Or, expressing this using `in` and tuples is simpler:

```
select t.*
from t
where (id, second_id, status) in
          (select second_id, id, status from t);
```